# Leaflet map more performance with a svg image

Tags: leaflet, zoom, phonegap

I created a leaflet-application with phonegap containing a svg image as my "baselayer". The performance is okay when i zoom in via double tap. But when i zoom in via two-finger-zoom the image starts to stutter and the zoom animation is delayed.

My solution was to remove the svg when zooming and add it again when zoom is finished. This actually works but freezes the application for 1 second when adding the svg layer.

Is there a solution with good performance?